# LinkedIn Javascript SDK Retrieve Profiles

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to retrieve any Profile data with the LinkedIn SDK right now. I am only able to retrieve my own data. Is there a way to retrieve like any Profile data or search for profiles with xyz Name and Show the results? I can't find usefull Information about this, neither in the offical documentation or elsewhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LinkedIn Javascript Api Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        onLoad:     onLinkedInLoad
        authorize: true
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLinkedInLoad(){
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", OnLinkedInAuth);
        }

        function OnLinkedInAuth() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").result(ShowProfileData);
        }

        function ShowProfileData(profiles) {
        var member = profiles.values[0];
        //var id=member.id;
        //var firstName=member.firstName; 
        //var lastName=member.lastName; 
        //var photo=member.pictureUrl; 
        //var headline=member.headline; 
            document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML =
            "<p id=\"" + member.id + "\">Hello " + member.firstName + " " + member.lastName + "</p>";
        }     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="IN/Login"></script>

    <div id="profiles"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways to do:

1. Use [Oauth2](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2). This means you have to get access token before you search profile by API.
2. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576913/linkedin-api-field-selectors), you must be one of Linkedin Partners.